# GUI for PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking for a GUI (Graphical User Interface) for PGf/TikZ, where I should be able to draw the diagrams by hand or generate a graph of a function, and the LateX code should be generated.

Comment: it's not really duplicate.  most of the answers there are about generic (png, svg, etc.) creation tools (like dia), and not about pgf/tikz generators.

Comment: @ivoWelch Agree. This question is not duplicated as it concerns with GUI for **TIKZ** only!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several such avaiable. Wikipedia has a list. Look at the external links at the bottom of the page

[Link to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ)

Comment: tried to remove my question edit, but did not see how.  should have been a note.   the tikz GUIs there rely on a deep windows .net toolchain, except ktikz and it dates to 2012.